# Invoke a Java method from an XSL FO file

Tags: java, xslt, methods, call, xsl-fo

I'm new to XSL FO and just going through the tutorials online. I was wondering if we could invoke a java method from an XSL FO file. I basically need to send some values to this java method from the xsl fo file. 
It would be great if someone could help me with this.
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You should probably rephrase your question to say something more about what you are trying to accomplish. I can think of three scenarios:

1) You actually want to do something to put appropriate data into XSL FO (not get something from it). In this case, you are normally processing some XML with XSL and using an appropriate XSLT processor, you can certainly call Java methods.

2) You really do as you say, want to get information from XSL FO. XSL FO is static and fed to an FO processor to format a document. If you want some information from this file, use an approriate Java method to parse the XSL FO (it is merely XML) and get the information from it.

3) What you really want is get some information from the composition process. You would only do this if you need some information about pagination or spatial placement. This actually would not be from the XSL FO. All XSL FO processors convert the XSL FO into an intermediate format. You would set up your application to process to one of these intermediate formats (which are XML) and process that to accomplish your task (such as measure or calculate pages or ?). If you are only "getting" information you would be set, but many applications allow you to also modify that intermediate file and feed only it back to the engine to change the output "in process".

One of these is likely what you are looking to do and the proper method to accomplish it.